# Flutter Cannot run Project.afterEvaluate(Closure) when the project is already evaluated

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, onesignal

Workaround way: Looks like there is dependecy of onesignal plugin on flutter_tools. The solution is to place onesignal plugin after it in the sequence in the "android/app/build.gradle":

```
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
```

After upgrading Flutter version from 2.8.1 to 2.10, I started getting the following error. I reinstalled Flutter but the result did not change. When I downgrade Flutter to 2.8.1, it works fine, but when I upgrade to 2.10 it doesn't.

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/aksoyhlc/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 421

 What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > **Cannot run Project.afterEvaluate(Closure) when the project is already evaluated.**

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUİLD FAILED in 798ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

***part of android/app/build.gradle file***

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
       
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } 
    }
    dependencies {
       
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.6, 0.99.99]'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
    }
}
allprojects {

    repositories {
        // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
        google()  // Google's Maven repository

    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
```

***android/build.gradle file***

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'

    }


}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
       /* maven {
            url "${project(':background_fetch').projectDir}/libs"
        }*/
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.0, on macOS 12.0.1 21A559 darwin-x64, locale
    tr-TR)
    • Flutter version 2.10.0 at /Users/aksoyhlc/flutter/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 5f105a6ca7 (4 days ago), 2022-02-01 14:15:42 -0800
    • Engine revision 776efd2034
    • Dart version 2.16.0
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/aksoyhlc/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.64.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.34.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Redmi Note 8 Pro (mobile) • ------- • android-arm64  • Android 11
      (API 30)
    • Chrome (web)              • chrome           • web-javascript • Google
      Chrome 98.0.4758.80

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available
```

Answer (score 12):

Looks like there is dependecy of onesignal plugin on flutter_tools.
The solution is to place onesignal plugin after it in the sequence in the "android/app/build.gradle":

```
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
```

Comment: This "fixes" the build but breaks notifications. See details at https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin/issues/184.

Comment: @shpitc what is flutterRoot here?

Comment: @nagendra, the Flutter SDK folder. I have it in C:\Flutter for example.

Comment: @shpitc got it.

Answer (score 7):

For those who are still getting this error. [This solution](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin/issues/184#issuecomment-1147889318) works for me.

The issue is that the OneSignal plugin doesn't compatible with Gradle 7.x version. So you can modify the Gradle version like below:

`android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9.2-all.zip
```

`android/build.gradle`

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
        // OTHERS
    }
```

Then you can initialize the OneSignal plugin in `android/app/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal
    }
    dependencies {
        // ...
        // OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.10, 0.99.99]'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
```

You should note that the OneSignal plugin must be placed above `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`, so placing it below `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` may cause the plugin not to work as expected.

Answer (score 5):

Have the same issue.
Still didn't solve it, but looks like something wrong with an onesignal plugin. If you will remove it, everything works. At least for me.

Issue opened in the OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin repo:
https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin/issues/184

Comment: This one is not solved for me. I've described my solution in the separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

All of these answers did not work for me, downgrading my gradle version from 7.1.2 to 4.1.0 in android/build.gradle works for me.