# Cannot run Project.afterEvaluate(Closure) when the project is already evaluated

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

**currently i am having this error:**

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1526]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.
C:\Users\Flutter\StudioProjects\nomadnet>flutter run
Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone x86 arm. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with
"--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\Flutter\flutter_windows_2.10.1-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 421

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Cannot run Project.afterEvaluate(Closure) when the project is already evaluated.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 37s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             38,8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

---

**i already tried this things:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/71014094/16241837
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/71009865/16241837
- i also tried more things but i don't know them anymore

---

**my code:**

app/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal
    }
    dependencies {
        // ...
        // OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.6, 0.99.99]'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.apps.social_circle"
            minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    android {
        defaultConfig {
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    onesignal_app_id: 'f0f22efa-186b-4b17-be29-f3f86e4d6184',
                    onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
            ]
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml' //This fixes a bug in FAN 5.0.1
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'



dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.3')
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

    // das ist für alle sachen sehr wichtig
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.2.4'
}
```

android/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

---

i have the latest flutter version and also the latest flutter plugin version.

PS: i use oneSignal.

Please help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that's a known issue with the OneSignal Grandle plugin.

[Github OneSignal Issue](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin/issues/184)

In the discussion some solutions are proposed, by they seem to broke OneSignal or to cause more issue.

Two of them are:

- *Place onesignal plugin after it in the sequence in the "android/app/build.gradle".* Credit: [Direnalex comment](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin/issues/184#issuecomment-1031102319)
- *Downgrade Flutter and Kotlin.* Credit: [Dgilperez comment](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin/issues/184#issuecomment-1051122471)

**My suggestion is to bring attention to the Github Issue so that it can be solved by the OneSignal community.**

Comment: I sat on the bug for days.

Comment: @liamspiegel it would be like that some times :)

Comment: yes, sometimes also for weeks

Comment: I am getting this issue and neither OneSignal or Flutter are referenced in the project. It was caused by referencing a version of `react-native` noted as an "Exceptional Release" `0.63.5` - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases?q=0.63.5&expanded=true

Answer (score 0):

to fix the following issues above, i want to see your flutter doctor, and the verbose once running the app.

but please try this first

`1. downgrade your pub library , then do a pub repair, and flutter clean.`

`Did this solved the issue? if not Then do the following below.`

`2. downgrade your flutter version, and choose the stable channel for the down graded version, do a flutter clean, then pub repair, and fix the codes of yours to match the down graded version.`

Comment: i have already and an solution that worked for me

Comment: ok sorry my bad, and that's great :>

Comment: no problem -- thank you that you have post an answer please don't delete this answer because maybe this answer will help somebody else